# Copy animation from object to bone using python

Tags: python, animation, armature

I have multiple animated objects and an armature with an equal amount of bones. I want to transfer the animation from the objects onto specific bones. How can I do this using python?

Comment: I would look into constraining the armature bones to the objects and baking the animation.

Comment: I figured it out using your idea, thank you.